# How to find the maximum probability of satisfying the conditions in all combinations of arrays

Tags: python, algorithm

for example, I got a list of tokens and each token's number of characters(length) is

```
length = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

and here is the list of each token's probability of [not insert a linefeed, insert a linefeed] after the token

```
prob =  [[9.9978e-01, 2.2339e-04],  [9.9995e-01, 4.9344e-05],  [0.9469, 0.0531],  
         [9.9994e-01, 5.8422e-05],  [0.9964, 0.0036],  [9.9991e-01, 9.4295e-05],  
         [9.9980e-01, 1.9620e-04],  [1.0000e+00, 5.2492e-08],  [9.9998e-01, 1.8293e-05],  
         [9.9999e-01, 5.1220e-06],  [1.0000e+00, 3.9795e-06],  [0.0142, 0.9858]]
```

and the result for the probabilies is

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

which means inserting a linefeed after the last token.
The whole length of this line is 21, and I would like to have a maximum of 20 characters per line.
In that case, I have to insert one (in this example, maybe more in other situations) more linefeed to make sure every line has 20 characters at most.
In this example, the best answer is

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

since the 3rd token gets the highest probability of inserting a linefeed.

My thought is to make all combinations of these probabilities.(Multiply them instead of adding) I got 12 tokens in this example, each token gets its 0-1 Classification Probability, so there are 2^12 kinds of combination. And I use the binary sequence to record every situation (since it's a 0-1 Classification Problem)and store them in a dictionary in format of [binary sequence, the combination of probabilities].

```
    for i in range(nums):
        num *= 2
    numx = bin(num)
    for i in range(num):
        numx = bin(numx - 1)
        str1 = numx.encode('ascii').decode('ascii')
        str1 = str1.lstrip('0b')
        probb = 1
        for k in range(len(str1)):
            x = str1[k]
            if int(x) == 0:          # [0, 1]
                probb *= prob_task2[k][0]
            else:
                probb *= prob_task2[k][1]
        dic[str1] = probb
```

Then I want to sort all kinds of combination, and search the possible result from high to low.
I make two loops for making all combinations. And another two loops for searching the combinations from top to low in order to meet the restriction of characters. But I got some troubles with the efficiency, since once there are 40 tokens, I have to count 2^40 kinds of combinations.
I am not good at algorithms, so I do want to ask is there an efficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: For open-ended questions like that, I recommend https://or.stackexchange.com rather than stackoverflow. The answers tend to be a lot more insightful than those on stackoverflow, which tend to be more about code and less about the problem.

Comment: @Stef I wish people would wait a bit before suggesting migrations. The OR folks would probably find the dynamic program here anyway, but it doesn't need their tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rephrase, you have a list of tokens of given lengths, each with an
independent probability of being followed by a line break, and you want
to find the maximum likelihood outcome whose longest line doesn’t exceed
the given max.

There is an efficient dynamic program (O(n L) where n is the number of
tokens and L is the line length). The idea is that we can prevent the
search tree from blowing up exponentially by pruning the less likely
possibilities that have the same current line length. In Python:

```py
import collections
import math

length = [2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
prob = [
    [9.9978e-1, 2.2339e-4],
    [9.9995e-1, 4.9344e-5],
    [0.9469, 0.0531],
    [9.9994e-1, 5.8422e-5],
    [0.9964, 0.0036],
    [9.9991e-1, 9.4295e-5],
    [9.998e-1, 1.962e-4],
    [1.0e0, 5.2492e-8],
    [9.9998e-1, 1.8293e-5],
    [9.9999e-1, 5.122e-6],
    [1.0e0, 3.9795e-6],
    [0.0142, 0.9858],
]
max_line_length = 20

line_length_to_best = {length[0]: (0, [])}
for i, (p_no_break, p_break) in enumerate(prob[:-1]):
    line_length_to_options = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line_length, (likelihood, breaks) in line_length_to_best.items():
        length_without_break = line_length + length[i + 1]
        if length_without_break <= max_line_length:
            line_length_to_options[length_without_break].append(
                (likelihood + math.log2(p_no_break), breaks + [0])
            )
        line_length_to_options[length[i + 1]].append(
            (likelihood + math.log2(p_break), breaks + [1])
        )
    line_length_to_best = {
        line_length: max(options)
        for (line_length, options) in line_length_to_options.items()
    }
_, breaks = max(line_length_to_best.values())
print(breaks + [1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly, but I need some time to understand it. Thank you sincerely!